# Fold and unfold animation of UIImageView using constraints

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

As you can see in my code bellow, I'm trying to make a fold/unfold animation using constraints. Certainly the gray background has the fold/unfold animation but the image itself doesn't.

How can I get same fold/unfold effect of the image itself?

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController {
    var folded: Bool = false
    var imagen: UIImageView!
    private var foldConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        let imagen = UIImageView(contentMode: .scaleAspectFill, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "gpointbutton"))
        imagen.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imagen.backgroundColor = .gray
        view.addSubview(imagen)
        self.imagen = imagen
        imagen.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        imagen.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        foldConstraint = imagen.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)
        createAnimationButton()
    }
    private func createAnimationButton() {
        let button = UIButton(title: "Animate", titleColor: .blue)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.addAction(for: .touchUpInside) { [weak self] (_) in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            self.folded = !self.folded
            if self.folded {
                self.foldConstraint.isActive = true
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
                    self.imagen.setNeedsLayout()
                    self.imagen.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()
                }
            } else {
                self.foldConstraint.isActive = false
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
                    self.imagen.setNeedsLayout()
                    self.imagen.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()
                }
            }
        }
        view.addSubview(button)
        button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to note here is that the `width` or `height` constraint is set to `0` (accurately also includes `0.1`), and the same is hidden.

Then you need to set the `height` constraint to be greater than `0.1`

```
foldConstraint = imagen.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)
```

Replace with this, temporarily set to 1

```
foldConstraint = imagen.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1)
```

Hide it at the end of the animation

```
        self.folded = !self.folded
        if self.folded {
            self.foldConstraint.isActive = true
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
                self.imagen.setNeedsLayout()
                self.imagen.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()
            }) { (completion) in
                self.imagen.isHidden = true
            }
        } else {
            self.imagen.isHidden = false
            self.foldConstraint.isActive = false
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
                 self.imagen.setNeedsLayout()
                 self.imagen.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()
             })
        }
```

#### Update:

`scaleAspectFill` is not suitable for animation, it should be set to `scaleAspectFit`

```
let imagen = UIImageView(contentMode: .scaleAspectFit, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "gpointbutton"))
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response and sorry for the misunderstood but I want to create the fold and unfold animation of the UIImageView, not just hiding it.  I've change the title and description of the question.

Comment: Yes, this program was tested by your code. You can try it. Don’t decide so fast.

Comment: @Ricardo You need to change the constraint of the height，Read my answer carefully

Comment: I did and the effect is the same. The image just hide or unhide without the fold and unfold animation.

Comment: How did you change it, because I wrote the demo with your code, the animation is working，Whether to add 'foldConstraint = imagen.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1)'

Comment: You can try here https://gist.github.com/rchampa/bb4e8465f8fb92ae0388f7f72c50aadf

Comment: I am very happy to help you. Each of my answers will be carefully written by demo verification. This is my responsibility.

Comment: The problem was the scaleAspectFill property, when I changed to scaleAspectFit everything works fine, and ofc your help telling me set constant to 1.

Comment: Sorry, I missed `scaleAspectFill`, I modified the answer.